# Blog or tutorial for layering different widgets and keeping some layers transparent

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

What i am trying to achieve is i have a alphabet 'A' on the screen. Inside the text body i want to show a container whose height is varying. So in the background screen lets say the color is green. The text 'A' on the screen is transparent. Inside 'A' text is filled with color yellow. But the color lowers its height level gradually. And a new color is revealed for the reduced height space, lets say pink.
[image]

Comment: can you add a picture of what you really wanted?

Comment: When i say lowers its height, i mean its an animated shape whose height decreases with time. So the yellow color level keeps descending to the base and pink color keeps increasing to the base.

Comment: in your original question you did not mention about any animation at all - but anyway, you can use `ShaderMask` with `blendMode: BlendMode.srcIn` and linear gradient as a shader

Comment: @pskink Can you refer me any content(blogs/documentation) which i need to cover to get a brief idea about all the required classes/options related to overlaying widgets. Or what are the various flutter classes i need to look into.

Comment: `AnimatedBuilder` / `ShaderMask` / `LinearGradient`

Comment: but if you really, really need to have A shaped hole in green layer and want to see what is below that green layer you should use `ColorFiltered` with blen mode srcOut

Comment: Thanks @pskink I will try that. Right now i am trying to gather the different classes/widgets i need to become familiar with to create something i mentioned above or something similar containing layers. I need to learn about - SHaderMask, BlendModes, ColorFiltered, Opacity.

Answer (score -1):

If your saying that your using text, changing height in order to change the color. Heres my solution in three step.

1.Use stack
2.Use Animated Container to lower the height
3.Use Timer with a duration of 1sec.

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (Timer t) => changeHight());
  }

  changeHight(){
    setState(() {
      textHeight = 200;
    });
  }


               Stack(
                      children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                      color: Colors.green,
                      width: 200.0,
                      height: 200.0,
                      child: Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                      child: Text("A",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 200,color: Colors.yellow),))
                    ),

                    AnimatedContainer(
                      alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                      duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
                      height: textHeight,
                      width: 200,
                      child:  Text("A",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 200,color: Colors.pink),)
                    )
                      ],
                    ),
```